# Import Tab - phpmyadmin - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: phpmyadmin, importerror

I need to import a .csv to overwrite a table in my database. However I can't get to the import screen because as soon as I click the Import tab, I get an Internal Server Error (Code 500). I don't get this error when I try the export tab (or any other tab). I've looked around a bit and see that a lot of people get this error due to the file type they're importing, but I can't even get that far.

Is this error something that's out of my control? I also tried on two other sites' databases, and I get the same error. Does anybody know if the site itself (phpmyadmin) is experiencing issues? Thanks a million.

Comment: does it say anything about nginx by any chance?

Comment: I should also mention that I haven't made any changes to any configurations or permissions. I've been doing this import quarterly for the past two years and have never encountered a problem.

Comment: It does not--just that there's an Internal Server Error with Error Text 500, and I can click to dismiss the alert.

Comment: have you looked at the error logs? and had a look at what the http 500 error message is? also post it on here

Comment: I have but I don't see anything that seems pertinent or any mention of a 500 error. Am I looking in the wrong place? I'm in the status tab looking at Server/Query Stats/Status Variables/Monitor/Advisor. I do see a possible performance issue saying that my server version is less than 5.1. Would that be related? Side note--the Monitor content isn't laid out as it should be. It looks like a bunch of <div> blocks overlapping each other instead of separate charts.

Comment: right firstly, are you using this on a server or desktop? also what os? if you are running a server do you have root permissions? also was this pre-configured or installed by yourself?

Comment: right so the error is on your server. is it linux on the server? and do you have ssh rights into the server to get to the logs? (thats if it is linux)

Comment: also i'd advise removing the link to your database hosting

Comment: before you go further, if you don't manage the server yourself. you maybe better asking the server admin to have a look at the logs for you.

Comment: ok i deleted that comment thanks. i will try to find out who really even works on this server. i'm not too clear on it to be honest. i just have routine tasks and haven't had any issues prior to this to have to seek out help. thank you so much for your help thus far, and i'll try to post again as soon as i have more information.

Comment: no problem. update this when you have more information.

Comment: I contacted the company that hosts our website, and it actually ended up being an issue with phpmyadmin on their server. Thank you again though for your insight. This is the first time I've posted here, and I'm pretty impressed with the response.

Comment: not a problem, just remember that if you do post anything on here make sure that it has as many examples as you can and make sure its programming orientated otherwise it will more then likely be marked down